# 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' when trying to call unmanaged function from C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllimport

I finally have a completed C++ DLL but I'm having trouble calling it from C#. It is definitely finding the DLL as when I remove it from the folder I get a different exception, 'DLLNotFoundException'. The full error description is "Unable to find an entry point named 'GetNewInstance' in DLL 'CComms.dll'". The functions are all exported in C++ like so

```
__declspec(dllexport) DWORD __stdcall GetNewInstance();
```

and I call it from C# like so

```
[DllImport("CComms.dll")]
private static extern uint GetNewInstance();
// ... and in main
uint inst = GetNewInstance();
```

When I use 'dumpbin /exports CComms.dll' I get some wierd output I'm not sure whether the function name is being mangled and that's why it cant find an entry point

```
7    6 00002FB0 ?GetNewInstance@@YGKXZ = ?GetNewInstance@@YGKXZ (unsigned long
__stdcall GetNewInstance(void))
```

I've tried using __cdecl instead of __stdcall, and had the same result. I'm so close to being done with this project, which I've loated all the way through, hopefully this is the last thing in my way.

Thanks.

Comment: I see you mention "CComms.dll", but the DllImport attribute seems to be looking for "VLTGLSCommsDLL.dll". Is that what's amiss?

Comment: "The functions are all exported in C++ like so" You could try adding `extern "C"` to the export declaration to get the usual `__stdcall` export name? I'd be surprised if .NET couldn't import both types though.

Comment: Sorry I should have explained that all of the exported functions are wrapped in an extern "C" block, I just showed one of the functions here as an example, and as for the the DLL name I recently made a change to that and just got mixed up between the old and the new when typing this up, it is looking for the correct DLL, and finds it, otherwise it would throw a DLLNotFoundException. Made change to code so that it now has the correct DLL name in all places.

Comment: Really? I'd have said that was a C++ mangling. I'd expect the C `__stdcall` mangling to be `_GetNewInstance@0`.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm unfamiliar with __thiscall, could you elaborate?

Comment: ... sorry, I meant the C++ __stdcall mangling. [__thiscall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek8tkfbw.aspx) is the C++ method calling convention.

Comment: Your C++ is declared as a unsigned long yet your C# code is only an unsigned integer.  Your calling conventions also do not match....which is a problem.

Comment: Oh I never noticed that in the dumpbin output, in the C++ code it is declared as a DWORD, and I thought the C# equivalent of DWORD was uint and that that would be handed by the interop?

Comment: @BillWalton - A DWORD is an **unsigned long** your C# code is expecting an unsigned 32-bit integer. This might not be the problem. I just noticed the difference.  Looking closer into what Microsoft describes as a DWORD it appears it also is a 32-bit integer.  Why are you usind DWORD instead of int or long or ect?

Comment: I used DWORD because the functions return error codes (or 0 for success), so there will never be a negative value, I'll try changing the return values to ints

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways of creating a DLL.

One is by getting the addresses of the functions (the oldschool way), and the second is by parameters and name (the "new" way, used by .net for example).

I imagine you are not using your C++ dll correctly

Maybe you should be using `GetProcAddress` [GetProcAddress Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/64tkc9y5%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Here is some documentation concerning [Dll exportation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/z4zxe9k8.aspx) which might come in useful

Answer (score 0):

Has the same problem with VB.NE
Didn't get this exception if function declared without __stdcall but had Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' warning.

in the library function declared

```
extern "C"  _declspec(dllexport)
int __stdcall GetLine(HWND hwnd, int iLine, TCHAR *buff)
```

Adde exports.def file to the dll project

```
EXPORT
  GetLine
```

and to the linker Additional Options

```
/DEF:"exports.def"
```

problem solved